# Dynamically change URL for share button on Facebook Embedded Posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Basically, my website hosts various embedded posts using the new Facebook Feature.  This allows users to like, comment and share other peoples content from my site.  What am I trying to achieve is, when a user shares somebody else's content via embedded post, it will show up on the Facebook Feed as via MY WEBSITE...not via the posts originator.  It can be done if when clicking the share button, I manually enter my app id in the url in place of theirs.  Can this be done dynamically by a piece of code?

Thank you in advance,
Gavin.

Answer (score 0):

You not mention which server side language used. Assumed PHP

```
 $url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo $url;?>"></div>
```

or Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.location.protocol = "http";
window.location.host = "example.com"
window.location.pathname = "index.html"
var shareURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;
document.write('<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="'+shareURL+'"></div>');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but it's not quite as simple as that.  If you embed a post on a website, the share functionality is within that, it is not an individual share button.